# Ampliar margen en gráfico

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tengo el siguiente df

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '

                           Porcentaje
Variable1                         0.6
Variable2                         0.4
Variable3                         0.23
Variable4                         0.19
Variable5                         0.10
Variable6                         0.04
Variable7                         0.0
Variable8                         0.0
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = 'NA')
```

Y quiero hacer el siguiente gráfico:

```
ggplot(my.data  ,aes( reorder(rownames(my.data ), Porcentaje),Porcentaje)) +
  geom_col(fill="steelblue") + coord_flip(expand = FALSE)+
  ggtitle ("Porcentaje de valores desconocidos")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  xlab("Variables") + ylab("Porcentaje")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que la primera barra no llegara tan al final del gráfico, sino que hubiera más margen, es decir, ampliar el eje x.
He probado con xlim pero no lo consigo.

Comment: A partir de la versión 3.0 de `ggplot2` la función `geom_col()` permite alternar entre los ejes `x` y `y`. Es decir, ya no es necesario usar `coord_flip()` para crear barras horizontales, es cuestión de mapear a `x` la variable que controla el largo de las barras y a `y` la la que le da el nombre. Resuelve este problema y algunos más.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes dejar que `ggplot` ajuste los márgenes mediante:

```
coord_flip(expand = TRUE)
```

Pero también podrías ajustar esta expansión de forma manual agregando:

```
# 10% a derecha e izquierda
scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.1, 0.1)))
```

Ten en cuenta que has hecho un "flip" de los ejes, y lo que ves como `x` en realidad es el eje `y`, puedes también entonces, ajustar la escala manualmene:

```
  ylim(-0.01,0.65)
```

o bien:

```
  scale_y_continuous(limits = (-0.01,0.65))
```